# Upgrade to mvc 4 manually by replacing dlls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, dll

Existing project uses following assemblies manually placed and referenced in *_bin_deployableAssemblies* folder.
This projects does not use NuGet on this.

I'm upgrading from MVC 3 to 4 by replacing the same dlls in above folder.
Is there any other dependency dlls I need to place there?

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
System.Web.Helpers.dll       
System.Web.Mvc.dll 
System.Web.Razor.dll       
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.dll       
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
```

Comment: I will be changing on web.config files and ProjectGuidTypes too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little bit more needed than just replacing DLLs. See this article: http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/12/upgrade-aspnet-mvc-3-project-to-mvc-4.html

Comment: Yes. I'm already doing that also. Should have mentioned before. Thanks.